# How to configure oozie shell action to run on all nodes

Tags: oozie

I have to make oozie shell action to run on all nodes for e.g creating parent directory for logs on local directory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, as far as I know. 
But you can try the below approaches initially proposed [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Execute-Shell-script-through-oozie-job-in-all-node/td-p/33136):

1. MapReduce action can run on all nodes, but requires Java application. [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Map+Reduce+Cookbook)
2. hadoop Streaming + MapReduce shell scripts. [link](http://www.oraclealchemist.com/news/tf-idf-hadoop-streaming-bash-part-1/); You can launch it as ssh or shell action in oozie